# Why is magnetic flux conserved in a magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, conservation-laws, gauss-law, electromagnetic-induction

Why is magnetic flux conserved in a magnetic field?
What rule tells this?

Comment: Why do you think it is conserved? What do you *mean* by “conserved?

Comment: Turn on a current and there is magnetic flux that wasn’t there before. How is that “conserved”? The premise of the question is false.

Comment: Do you mean why is $\nabla\cdot B = 0$ ?

Comment: Magnetic flux is not conserved as stated by others. It’s just that nature “abhores” a change in flux .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are answers to that [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/584178/why-does-nature-abhor-a-change-in-flux). What is conserved, is energy. Ultimately, what is happening above is Lenz's law which is a statement of the conservation of energy.